# How to detect Pyserial

Tags: python, pyserial

I'm trying to run a code which requires `pyserial`, shown below.

```
import serial

port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0", baudrate = 115200, timeout=3.0)

while True:
    port.write("\r\nSay something:")
    rcv = port.read(10)
    port.write("\r\nYou sent:" + repr(rcv))
```

However, I'm getting an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Python\test_1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import serial
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'serial'
```

I am not sure why they cannot find 'serial' because I already installed it. I downloaded the file pyserial-3.4.tar.gz (md5) from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyserial

I then went to command prompt with admin privileges and changed the directory and used

`python setup.py install`

I kept getting the same error so I even tried

```
pip install pyserial
```

Also in command prompt once again with admin privileges. I still get the same error. Any idea why?

Comment: are you sure pyserial package in you enviroment, Can you quick check using ```pip freeze``` commad if packge exist or not?

Comment: do you have multiple versions of python installed ?

Comment: Did you check `pyserial` using `pip list | grep pyserial` ?

Comment: Try using 'sypder'  with annaconda, its a python package manager and comes with a lot of packages pre-installed including pyserial.

Comment: @ManojJadhav yes, and it shows Pyserial 3.4

Comment: @MaheshKaria no, just one

Comment: @ByeonggukGong checking  `pip list` gives me  `pip (9.0.1)
pyserial (3.4)
setuptools (28.8.0)`